# Gatsby: Allow non-existing fields in GraphQL Queries

Tags: wordpress, graphql, graphql-js, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby with the Wordpress source plugin. So far so good. But the thing is I am querying fields that might or might not be there, in this case, the featured image of a post.
Here is my query:

```
{
allWordpressPost(sort: { fields: [date] }) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          excerpt
          slug
          featured_media
          better_featured_image {
            wordpress_id
            alt_text
            caption
            description
            media_type
            post
            source_url
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

It works well when the featured image is set, but fails miserably otherwise.
And so my question: Is there any way in GraphQL to query an optional field? To add a default value to a required field?
I am all too new to GraphQL so I'm not even sure that's possible at this point.
Thank you.

Comment: Where exactly is it failing? The Query or the Render?

Comment: @Scriptonomy The query. When the field is not found.

Comment: You might have luck with the schema explorer in the GraphiQL at http://localhost:8000/___graphql

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://www.gatsbycentral.com/gatsby-ignores-empty-fields) explains the back story, but in short, you need to make sure that at least 1 of your WordPress posts has the featured image. Then the `better_featured_image` field will always exist.

In javascript, if you try to access `allWordpressPost.edges.node.better_featured_image.wordpress_id` and `better_featured_image` does not exist, you'll get a syntax error.

Without knowing what "fails miserably" specifically means, not sure what else to suggest.